# How can I use offline-directline for Microsofts Botframework v4?

Tags: html, azure, botframework, chatbot, direct-line-botframework

I need to run the **microsoft botframework v4 on-premise** since company internal restrictions forbid me to register the bot on Microsoft Azure or use the connector in the cloud.
My idea is to use **[offline-directline](http://www.npmjs.com/package/offline-directline)** to emulate the connector locally. 
To my knowledge, the package has been built for Microsoft Botframework V3 and not v4. Has anybody managed to use it for v4?

I followed through instructions however got stuck trying to implement the web chat client. Where and how do I implement

```
BotChat.App({
    directLine: {
        secret: params['s'],
        token: params['t'],
        domain: params['domain'],
        webSocket: false // defaults to true
    },
```

in the index.html file of directline v4? The documentation of "offline-directline" is only for Botframework v3.

Is there a sample repository where I could find some info from?

Comment: Would you like to upvote my answer and mark it as correct?

Answer (score 5):

Please refer to the instructions in the [BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) repo to see how to host Web Chat v4 in a website. You'll find something that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="webchat" role="main"></div>
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
        directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token: 'YOUR_DIRECT_LINE_TOKEN' }),
        userID: 'YOUR_USER_ID',
        username: 'Web Chat User',
        locale: 'en-US',
        botAvatarInitials: 'WC',
        userAvatarInitials: 'WW'
      }, document.getElementById('webchat'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Rather than passing the same kind of object to `window.WebChat.renderWebChat`'s `directLine` parameter as you would to `BotChat.App`'s `directLine` parameter, you need to pass the object to `window.WebChat.createDirectLine`. The object in question is a [`DirectLineOptions`](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLineJS/blob/master/src/directLine.ts#L350) object.

```
    window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
        directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
            secret: params['s'],
            token: params['t'],
            domain: params['domain'],
            webSocket: false // defaults to true
        }),
```

If you don't want to have to pass in any parameters to your Web Chat client, you can include them inline:

```
            secret: '',
            token: '',
            domain: 'http://localhost:3000/directline',
            webSocket: false // defaults to true
```

And if you're not particular about running Web Chat in your own HTML page, I recommend foregoing offline-directline and just using the [Bot Emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-emulator), which is great for interacting with local bots.

Comment: Thx, that works. Now I want to disconnect completely from azure but with Luis running. Even though I deleted the BotFileSecret and all .bot settings except for luis, Im still connected to azure. When testing, I can see activity in azures request monitoring for the bot. This seems strange.

Comment: Are you running the bot locally or on a remote server? Did you delete your bot resource from Azure? Do your bot settings still contain an app ID and password?

Comment: Its running locally. I deleted credentials in the files: "botname".bot, .env and index.js and still get requests activity. It runs fine locally when I stop the bot service and disable directline app service. Are the credentials and endpoints cached somewhere? Also disabling luis and running offline works.
What concerns are there to run offline-directline in production? We need a local connector due to comp. policy.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but have you considered running LUIS in a container? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-container-howto

Comment: @KyleDelaney looks like it is not working anymore, I tried using direct line of bot emulator and it worked without an issue but with offline-directline I am always getting "RangeError: Invalid time value", can you help if possible?

Comment: @Shubham - I don't know what time value you're talking about. You should post a new question.

Comment: I tried the exact above html and changed the js code to pass the correct params but I get an error as shown here - https://i.imgur.com/8sa58Fz.png. I have the bot deployed using java botbuilder framework that exposes an endpoint http://localhost:8080/api/messages hence I entered http://localhost:8080/directline as the domain url. Wonder what could be wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: @AndyDufresne - You say you have a bot deployed, but then you say you're trying to access it using localhost. These two things do not go together. My suggestion is to post a new question.