# Is there any way to develop own Webchat instead of Microsoft Botframework-Webchat

Tags: botframework, web-chat

I don't want to keep any dependency on Microsoft Botframework registration for Webchat. I have successfully deployed my Bot Code in Shared Server instead of AzurePortal, But to use the Webchat I have to register the Bot in AzurePortal.

My concern is to develop own Webchat which will directly communicate with the Bot API Endpoint.

Have anyone work on this situations.

Comment: Was my answer sufficient? If so, please "accept" and upvote it so others can quickly find the answer and I can clear this from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Answer (score 3):

To clarify, bots communicate via:

```
User interaction with DirectLine Client ->
    DirectLine API receives data and sends to bot ->
        Bot hosted anywhere receives message
```

WebChat is just a DirectLine client. *If* you want to build your own WebChat, you can [clone the repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) and build it yourself. Note, however, that all this does is make it so you can host your own `webchat.js` file.

I believe that what you're actually looking for is to build your own [DirectLine API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-concepts?view=azure-bot-service-4.0). The only way to do so, currently, is to develop it in Node with the [`offline-directline` npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/offline-directline). This is not an official Bot Framework package, but will accomplish what you need. To then use WebChat with `offline-directline`, you would just need to [change `domain` property when rendering WebChat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55812986/how-can-i-use-offline-directline-for-microsofts-botframework-v4).