# Steps to deploy botbuilder chatbot locally through webchat

Tags: java, botframework, web-chat

I want to build a bot in java using the the microsoft bot builder framework. I am trying out the samples provided [here](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-java/tree/main/samples). I would like to know how can I **locally** deploy a bot developed using botbuilder-java framework on webchat.

I have blindly tried the html listed on [another ST link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55820767/537503) as below

```js
window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
    directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
        secret: '',
        token: '',
        domain: 'http://localhost:8080/directline',
        webSocket: false // defaults to true
    })})
```

but that that fails with various errors on console. Kindly guide me on how could I proceed. Note my bot and the web chat clients needs to be deployed locally (**not on emulator**). No azure deployments.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that javascript code was incomplete. The complete code is

```
window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
        directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
            secret: '',
            token: '',
            domain: 'http://localhost:7070/directline',
            webSocket: false // defaults to true
        }),
        styleOptions: {
            hideUploadButton: true
        }
    }, document.getElementById('webchat'))
```